# create object parent which nested children in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i want to create 1 objects nested document like:

Children:

chil1:

```
{ name: 'Mimi',                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        parent: 537258f63eb92b3201b65e56,                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        _id: 537258f63eb92b3201b65e57,                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        __v: 0 },
```

chil2

```
{ name: 'Kiki',                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    parent: 537258f63eb92b3201b65e56,                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    _id: 537258f63eb92b3201b65e58,                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    __v: 0 }
```

Parent:(What i want)

```
[ { name: 'John',                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    _id: 537258f63eb92b3201b65e56,                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    __v: 0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    children: [ { name: 'Mimi',                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    parent: 537258f63eb92b3201b65e56,                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    _id: 537258f63eb92b3201b65e57,                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    __v: 0 },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  Children:[ { name: 'Mimi',                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    parent: 537258f63eb92b3201b65e56,                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    _id: 537258f63eb92b3201b65e57,                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    __v: 0 },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  { name: 'Kiki',                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    parent: 537258f63eb92b3201b65e56,                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    _id: 537258f63eb92b3201b65e58,                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    __v: 0 } ]
```

is possible to create data on mongooese with nodejs(express)?
it is similar this question [mongoose: How to insert a single subdocument - not an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627976/mongoose-how-to-insert-a-single-subdocument-not-an-array) 
but in this case, the children only stored id of child, not all the object ? 
Here is my model file:

```
const schema:mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    name: String,
    parentCategory: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'parent',
    },
    childCategories: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'child',
    }], 
});
```

Normally result :

```
 { name: 'John',                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            _id: 537258f63eb92b3201b65e56,                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            __v: 0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            children: [Chil1_id, Chil2_id]
}
```

Comment: any suggestion will appreciate!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)?

Here is a simple example:

```
Parent.find().populate("children").exec(...)
```

As long as you specify the children's ref to a model, mongoose is smart enough to join the children with the parents.